# Automount in Xfce4 just stopped working

Tags: gentoo, udev, thunar, xfce

A little while ago my usb drives stopped auto mounting. It might have been after an update but not sure where to look.

I have been manually mounting them as root and that is a pain. Is there maybe even something better that I can have more control over the mounting? I would like a small program that would let me mount and unmount drives with one click to a folder in `/mnt/(device name)` with user read/write permissions.

Udev is kind of a gray area/black magic to me. I have tried 100 times to figure it out but I can't help but think there should be a much simpler way. Such as in Puppy Linux how you can open the mount menu and mount/unmount each device. Though every thing in Puppy runs as root so it is easier.

I am running Gentoo on AMD64 (amdfam10).

One side question, How can you tell which `/dev/...` files are currently representing actual devices?

Here is the last 30 lines fresh after plugging in a usb drive

```
Jun 26 15:19:41 core dbus[9204]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit' (using servicehelper)
Jun 26 15:20:06 core dbus[9204]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit': timed out
```

Comment: First place to look is /var/log/messages. Are there any messages related to your automount-tries?

Comment: Look through /dev/disk for more human readable entries with symlinks to actual device nodes.

Comment: `Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit': timed out`, how did you started XFCE4 ?

Comment: I start it using GDM kinda the same smiler as ubuntu karmic cola.

Comment: started using XDM not GDM

Comment: XDM is a problem, [same issue, different color](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150539/how-to-make-xfce-show-the-shutdown-menu).

Comment: how is xdm a problem it worked before then it just stopped